# Вырезать из одного файла и вставить в другой

Tags: json, bash, sed

Объясню ситуацию, есть скрипт который делает то, что нужно, и потом выкидывает *.log* файл в определённую папку, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы из этого *.log* файла взялось определённое значение, которое находится между словами A1 и B2, например, число 100, и есть файл *text.txt*, в котором находится некий список, и нужно, отредактировав его, вставить туда значение в определённую строку, например, заменить в одном месте число 95 числом, которое мы получили из лога, 100, завтра, например, в логе будет 105 и нужно будет заменить число 100 числом 105.

Чуть проще суть: текстовые утилиты (например, `sed`) согласно сценарию выдергивают из лога определенное содержимое и вставляют в другие места других файлов.

Как мне можно сделать такое? Я вот нашёл как можно дёрнуть с одного файла текст между двумя значениями, но пока не знаю как сохранять его в другие файлы только в определённые места без потерь остальных значений в файле.

Comment: критерий замены уточните пожалуйста прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit])

Comment: Здравствуйте Александр. я вот только недавно читал ваш ответ на то - как можно узнать содержимое файла между двумя переменными. уточните пожалуйста, критерии в смысле? что на что заменить нужно? и да - наверное нужно таки не вырезать, а просто узнать значение - без редактирования лога. я про заголовок.  извините если что туплю, я в этом новичок вообще.

Comment: скрипт проверяет баланс на определённом сайте,потом выводит лог по адресу /home/$data/balance с индивидуальным именем. нужно прочитать содержимое лога и узнать параметр pointsBalance, я так понял легче всего задать параметр между какими словами нужно читать, вот ваш код: s/.*начало//;s/конец.*//. есть документ .txt - в нём список аккаунтов и баланс: например Account: Account1 и на след строке: Balance: 111( и вот сюда заместо 111 нужно всякий раз подставлять значение взятое из лога).

Comment: Критерий замены - это как узнать то место в целевом файле, куда надо вставить значение. Например если бы мы точно знали, что надо просто заменить 95 на 105 то написали бы `s/95/105/`.

Comment: да, про это тоже думал, но цифры должны быть всякий раз разные, скрипт выполняет проверку раз в день. например сегодня - баланс 100, завтра будет - 110, нужно всякий раз менять эти цифры на актуальные из лога. может, нужно что-то вроде всегда менять значение на 2 строке 2-го слова? не знаю прокатит ли подобное с цифрами.

Comment: Если слово после которого идет цифра известно, то что то в этом роде `'2,1 s/word [0-9]\+/word 105/'` где "2,1" заменять вторую строку, только ее одну

Comment: Дайте вывод строки в которой ищем и вывод строки куда вставляем и опишите что в этих строках является динамически изменяемыми элементами а что статичными

Comment: вывод строки в которой ищем: "createDate":1517749172}],"totalCount":267,"pointsBalance":950,"creditValue":"25.05"}} а это вывод строки в которую вставляем: Account_01 (email1@mail.ru): 819 points = 16.38$ credits. Нужно узнать значение pointsBalance и creditValue из лога, и вставить их взамен старых значений в .txt файле. Т.е. статичным в документе является всё, кроме значений двух чисел - например 819 points, и 16.38 должны являться динамичными.

Comment: Господи, у вас JSON?! Так и пользуйтесь соответствующими инструментами! Не надо городить огород на языках программирования, на которых это решить трудно!

Answer (score 0):

```
account_name='Account_01'
actual_balance="$(grep -oE 'pointsBalance":[0-9]+,' file_for_get.txt | \
    grep -oE '[0-9]+')"

sed -Ei "/${account_name}/s/:\s+[0-9]+/: ${actual_balance}/" file_for_change.txt
```

> account_name это на случай, если в файле, где нужно поменять значение, не один аккаунт. Впринципе туда можно и e-mail вписать, результат не поменяется.
>    Если в строке из которой берется значение тоже есть идентификатор аккаунта то вторая строка должна выглядеть так:

```
actual_balance="$(grep "${account_name}" file_for_get.txt | \
    grep -oE 'pointsBalance":[0-9]+,' | grep -oE '[0-9]+')"
```

**НА GAWK**
Вариант на gawk, но если в строке из которой берется значение тоже есть идентификатор аккаунта то нужно всю строку видеть целиком, чтобы дописать до рабочего состояния.

```
awk -F ':' '$? ~ account_name sub(/\,.*$/,"",$?);{print $?}' \
account_name="$account_name" file_for_get.txt
```

Так должна выглядеть строка если во входящих данных есть имя аккаунта. Вместо вопросов должны стоять номера полей вывода.
А вот это будет работать с тем, что Вы дали:

```
account_name='Account_01'
actual_balance="$(awk -F ':' '{sub(/\,.*$/,"",$4);print $4}')" file_for_get.txt
awk -i inplace '$1 == account sub(/[0-9]+/,balance,$3); {print $0}' \
    balance=$actual_balance account=$account_name file_for_change.txt
```

Вот так меняет оба значения:

```
account_name='Account_01'
actual_balance="$(awk -F ',|}|"|:' '{print $13":"$18}' file_for_get.txt)"
sed -Ei "/${account_name}/s/:\\s+[0-9]+/: ${actual_balance%%:*}/;s/points =\\s+[0-9\\.]+/points = ${actual_balance##*:}/" file_for_change.txt
```

Или вместо `sed` попробуйте awk в команде замены. Вот так

```
awk -i inplace '$1 == account sub(/[0-9]+/,bal,$3) sub(/[0-9\.]+/,cred,$6) {print $0}' \
    bal="${actual_balance%%:*}" cred="${actual_balance##*:}" \
    account="$account_name" file_for_change.txt
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80891/discussion-on-answer-by-andrey-karpov--------).

Comment: Ой-ой-ой, не надо! Не надо решать задачу, не предназначенным для её решения инструментом. Там же JSON, а вы регулярными выражениями по нему... :(

Comment: Ну вот чем умею ))))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651946/find-the-value-of-key-from-json (попробуйте `jq`)

Comment: Что-то типа такого должно сработать `jq -r '.. | select(objects and .pointsBalance) | @sh "a=\(.pointsBalance)"' my_cool_json.json` (это вывод для импорта в shell, можно этого избегать, если язык программирования другой)